# Menu overflow-y: scroll but hiding the sub.menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, overflow, wordpress-theme-astra

I'm trying to set my max height menu by putting an `overflow-y: scroll`, but I noticed that the sub left menu is hidden. I can't get the trick how to scroll the Y value and authorise the X value.

Here is the code:

```
.ast-desktop .main-header-menu.ast-menu-shadow .sub-menu{
max-height: 315px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't know the specific page through your code snippet. Please release your page image. Or you can use a hidden menu for fixed positioning

```
display:fixed
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, 
the page is : https://www.publicitizz.com